# map with custom class having constructor with argument

Tags: c++

When I define an argument to the constructor, its object can't be set to a map:

```
#include <map>

class Foo
{
public:
    int fooInt;
    Foo(int fooInt)
    : fooInt(fooInt)
    {};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(2);
    std::map<int, Foo> fooMap;
    fooMap[1] = foo;
    return 0;
}
// won't compile
```

If no argument (i.e. define `Foo()` and declare `Foo foo`), this works. Why?

I actually think I'm missing something very basic... but I can't figure out what is meant by the long error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `operator[]` will insert a default constructed object if the key doesn't already exist in the map.

You're probably looking for `insert` for non-default-constructable object types.

Answer (score 5):

`std::map::operator[]` requires the value type (or `mapped_type`) to be satisfy the DefaultInsertable concept. From [map.access]:

> ```
> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
> ```
>
> Effects: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.
>   **Requires: `key_type` shall be `CopyInsertable` and `mapped_type` shall be `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.**
>   Returns: A reference to the `mapped_type` corresponding to `x` in `*this`.
>   Complexity: Logarithmic

`Foo` declares its own constructor that disables the implicit generation of a default constructor, so it's not default-constructible.

The solution is to either declare a default constructor or use the `emplace()` method to construct a value type in-place:

```
fooMap.emplace(1, foo);
```